# voltage keeper digital circuit

Tags: voltage, digital-logic

How do I create a digital circuit that does the following.

The output voltage Vout is at 0V originally.
If the input voltage Vin changes from 0V to 1V, the Vout should also goes to 1V and will keep as 1V no matter how Vin changes later on.

Comment: you wait for a rising input signal, set the output high and end the program?

Comment: What you're lookong for is a flip flop. But usually digital logic works with 3.3V or 5V.
What kind of signal is your input? How fast does it rise from 0V to 1V? Is it high impedance? What do you expect from the ourtput signal? Does it have to switch fast? What is the acceptable delay? What is the current draw on the output?

Comment: What shall happen if Vin raises to more than 1V, 1st case: initially, and 2nd case: later?